# C# Kubernetes Client Exec Command into Pod Container Issue

Tags: file, kubernetes, post, containers, exec

I have a custom web application written in .NET7 and I am using Kubernetes Client (C#) to interact with a Kubernetes Cluster (Azure). So far so good, everything is working as expected unit I reached the point where I need to communicate with a Pod Container.

Let' start with an easy example by just creating a new file:

The following command returns BadRequest regardless what I have tried so far:

```
string command_test = "touch servers_.json";
var stream_test = client.CoreV1.ConnectPostNamespacedPodExec(podname, space, command_test, container, true, true, false, false);
```

Then switched to WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync instead of ConnectPostNamespacedPodExec (uses vargs) and then I noticed the following (in this example I try to make a file with content):

```
//string[] command_test = { "touch servers_.json" }; //DOES NOT WORK
//string[] command_test = { "touch", "servers_.json" }; //DOES WORK
client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync(podname, space, command_test, container, true, true, false, false).Result;
```

In the above example seems that the touch command works when every word is separated by comma and quotes.

```
//string[] command_test = { "echo 'test' > servers_.json" }; //DOES NOT WORK
//string[] command_test = { "echo", "'test' > servers_.json" }; //DOES NOT WORK
//string[] command_test = { "echo", "'test'", ">", "servers_.json" }; //DOES NOT WORK
//var websocket_test = client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync(podname, space, command_test, container, true, true, false, false).Result;
```

But the same scenario using echo does not work whatever I tried even by splitting the words like the touch command.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd normally expect you to "communicate with a container" by sending network requests to it via a Service.  `kubectl exec` is more of a debugging tool.

Comment: That is definitely true, but when the application need files inside like pgadmin for example which needs servers and passfile that need to change occasionally and does not have an API for that, then it is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answers:
This is because the redirection operator (>) is interpreted by the shell, not by the echo command. Therefore, you need to invoke a shell to execute your command with the redirection. For example, you can try this:

```
string[] command_test = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 'test' > servers_.json" };
```